# In Python: How to deal with zero at first position in condition

Tags: python-3.x

I found some strange behavior in python. Possibly my logic is not correct.

```
1 and 2 and 3 in range(5)
Expected: True
Outcome: True

2 and 1 and 99 in range(5)
Expected: False
Outcome False

2 and 1 and 0 in range(5)
Expected: True
Outcome: True
```

Now the tricky one:

```
0 and 1 and 2 in range(5)
Expected: True
Outcome: 0
```

I am sure there is someone who makes me find my logical error.

Comment: `1 and 2 and 3 in range(5)` ==> `(1 is truthy) and (2 is truthy) and (3 in range(5) is truthy)`. Also read about short-circuiting of boolean operators.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to test multiple variables against a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-to-test-multiple-variables-against-a-value)

Comment: Actually it is: How to test multiple variables against multiple values / a list of values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In each expression, only the last number is checked against the `range`. The previous ones are evaluated "as is". In python, the expression `if i:` evaluates to True if `i` is not 0.

The value returned from the expressions (boolean or int) depends on what the conditions are. If you leave just `1 and 2` for example, the result will be the last int. However, since you have the `v in range(n)` expression, which returns `True` or `False`, the result is cast into a boolean value.

Now, due to [short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation), in the last case, only the zero gets evaluated. So the result is not cast into a boolean and 0 is returned.

**Edit**: After reading the comments, it becomes clear that you want to check if `k` number exist in `range(n)`. For that, you cannot use the simple expressions you've shown. You need to check if every individual value exists in the range. One - inefficient - approach would be this

```py
if all([v in range(n) for v in values]):
    print("All values exist in the range")
```

---

**Edit 2** (by @Pranav Hosangadi)

Side note:
Since the `all()` function takes [generator expressions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/), you can avoid the list-comprehension altogether. When you do this, the generator expression will only calculate as many items as needed for the `all()` to short-circuit. On the other hand, the list-comprehension approach will calculate *all* elements in the list, and then run `all()` on that list. Here's a simple example:

```
l = [100] * 10000
l[-1] = 0

def f1(): # Using generator
    return all(li == 0 for li in l)

def f2(): # Using list comp
    return all([li == 0 for li in l])
```

Now for the generator-expression approach, `all()` needs to calculate only the first element to know that it will short-circuit to `False`. However, the list-comprehension approach calculates *all* elements of the list first. All but the last element of this list are `False`. Then, `all()` takes this list and short-circuits at the first element. Running some timing on these functions:

```
import timeit

timeit.timeit('f1()', setup='from __main__ import f1, l', number=10000)
# Out: 0.006381300001521595

timeit.timeit('f2()', setup='from __main__ import f2, l', number=10000)
# Out: 5.257489699986763
```

`f1()` is *significantly* faster than `f2()`.